# Error In design time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, error-handling

Make sure "AjaxControlToolkit.Properties.Resources.NET4.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "AjaxControlToolkit" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

How to solve this Error?

Comment: Please put some code to help us understand better.